Host files not working when editing it via Nano but works when using SelfControl?
So I'm trying to edit my host files using sudo nano /etc/hosts so it can block some sites, but while I can edit and save it, no website is blocked.
Here's a real head scratcher: when I block the same sites using https://selfcontrolapp.com/, everything works.
It's not the content of the file or the formatting - while SelfControl was running/working, I literally copied/pasted the modified Host File on Terminal and used it as my new Host file (I pasted it and everything is identical).
Does anyone know what's going on? I've flushed the cache, did sudo chflags noschg /etc/hosts, changed 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1, but nothing seems to work. I suspected it might be caused by https://github.com/2ndalpha/gasmask or https://switchhosts.vercel.app/, but I already uninstalled them.

After manually editing the hosts file, and blackholing e.g. foo.com, what is the output of dscacheutil -q host -a name foo.com?

@luckman212 it says name: foo.com ip_address: 50.16.218.27, but foo.com is not blocked. However, when I block it via SelfControl and use the same function, it also says the same thing, but foo.com is blocked.

That app installs a privileged background task that may be preempting the hosts file. I suggest that you uninstall it completely according to the developer's instructions (not by just dragging something to the Trash). As a test, you can disable it without uninstalling by running this command in a shell:
sudo launchctl disable system/org.eyebeam.selfcontrold

If you wish, you can re-enable it this way:
sudo launchctl enable system/org.eyebeam.selfcontrold


yep, this is it - thank you!
